# How to bind my job to intel xeon phi coprocessor?

Tags: xeon-phi, intel-mic

I have a server with four mic cards (mic0-mic3), and it works well. how to bind a parallel job(mic_app) to mic0, other parallel job can not run in mic0. how to detect the mic0 has been running for a parallel job(mic_app).

Comment: You should probably add a tag for the relevant programming language (unless you're looking for a tool external to the process, in which case, you might be better off on the appropriate Stack Exchange for your OS).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Restricts the offload process to use only the coprocessors specified as the value of the variable.

Set this variable to a comma separated list of target device numbers in the range 0 to (number_of_devices_in_the_system -1), where 0 is the first coprocessor in the system, and (number_of_devices_in_the_system -1) is the last coprocessor in the system.

Coprocessors available for offloading are numbered logically. The function _Offload_number_of_devices() returns the number of available coprocessors. Coprocessor indices that you use in the target specifier of the offload pragmas are in the range 0 to number_of_devices_in_the_system-1.

Default: The offload process uses all devices.

Example: OFFLOAD_DEVICES = 1,2

On a system with more than two coprocessors installed, this setting enables the application to use only coprocessors 1 and 2. Offloads to coprocessors 0 or 1 are performed on the second and third physical coprocessors. Offloads to target numbers higher than 1 wrap-around so that all offloads remain within coprocessors 0 and 1. The function _Offload_number_of_devices() executed on a coprocessor return 0 or 1, when the offload is running on the first or second coprocessor.

[Supported Environment Variables](https://software.intel.com/en-us/node/522775)

Comment: For example, https://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/intel-many-integrated-core/topic/391262